# How do I extend a typings declaration?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using an npm module that has declarations in the DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped github repo, but typings for the module are incomplete.

I have made a pull request to get the missing declarations in, however until its accepted I need to have a way to temporarily extend the incomplete declaration.

Ideally I would like to be able to have a `temporaryTypings.d.ts` file in my project root where I can add declarations for every situation like this that I run into.

Answer (score 1):

You can install definitions from non-DefinitelyTyped source, like your fork of DT:

```
# (this example is taken from https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings )
# If you need a specific commit from github. 
$ typings install d3=github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/d3/d3.d.ts#1c05872e7811235f43780b8b596bfd26fe8e7760
```

`npm` since typescript 2 can install module from specific git repo as well.

Comment: Good idea, how would I use the new npm @types syntax to do this?

Comment: @nhjk `@types/pkg` are npm packages as well. I guess one should be able to publish a non-offical package with updated content, or just use a local npm package with `npm-link`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always have some `project.d.ts` file somewhere in your source file.

You can reference to it from some entry point like `/// <reference path="path/to/project.d.ts" />` or from your `tsconfig.json` and just add the typings that are working for you there.

For example my global file usually consists :

```
declare module "leftpad" {
    var t : any;
    export = t;
}
```

Which helps me to import my modules without `require`. After the definition files are available, you can install them with `npm install @types/leftpad --save-dev` and then just remove that module declaration from your `global.d.ts` file.